# C# Performances, Array versus Span from the Memory Buffer

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management, .net-core

I'm testing the performances of use a standard C# array vs use the Memory Buffer. The Standard Array wins. I don't get how the standard array is more fast than use the span from the memory buffer. The documentation say that the memory buffer is supposed to be used in high performances scenarios. I'm using the Release optimized configuration.

```
class Program
{
    private static void MemoryPoolTest(IMemoryOwner<long> owner)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var innerCounter = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    owner.Memory.Span[innerCounter++] = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                }
            }
            var result = owner.Memory.Slice(0, innerCounter - 1);
        }
    }

    private static void ArrayTest()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var innerCounter = 0;
            Span<long> array = new long[1000];
            for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    array[innerCounter++] = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                }
            }
            var result = array.Slice(0, innerCounter - 1);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        var m = new List<long>();
        var a = new List<long>();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        using var owner = MemoryPool<long>.Shared.Rent(1000);
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sw.Restart();
            MemoryPoolTest(owner);
            sw.Stop();
            m.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            sw.Restart();
            ArrayTest();
            sw.Stop();
            a.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(m.Skip(10).Average());
        Console.WriteLine(a.Skip(10).Average());
    }
}
```

Comment: I see about 3 *"why is this slower"* questions a day. They usually break down to incorrect benchmark methodology, or trying to race apples to oranges. For starters its not an array vs memory. and you are calling memory.Span per iteration which is fairly intensive. however, you are still racing apples and oranges.

Comment: Yeah, except in this case it is bad code that can easily be optimized ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in using owner.Memory.Span for each iteration. Assigning the Span to a variable before to iterate reduce the useless operations and the BufferMemory wins

```
class Program
{
    private static void MemoryPoolTest(Span<long> span)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var innerCounter = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    span[innerCounter++] = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                }
            }
            var result = span.Slice(0, innerCounter - 1);
        }
    }

    private static void ArrayTest()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var innerCounter = 0;
            Span<long> array = new long[1000];
            for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                if (j % 3 == 0)
                {
                    array[innerCounter++] = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
                }
            }
            var result = array.Slice(0, innerCounter - 1);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        var m = new List<long>();
        var a = new List<long>();
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        using var owner = MemoryPool<long>.Shared.Rent(1000);
        var span = owner.Memory.Span;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sw.Restart();
            MemoryPoolTest(span);
            sw.Stop();
            m.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            sw.Restart();
            ArrayTest();
            sw.Stop();
            a.Add(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(m.Skip(10).Average());
        Console.WriteLine(a.Skip(10).Average());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A `Span` is allocated (or moved to) the heap(the stack), A `Memory<T>` is more likeliy from managed memory.

It depends on the concrete CPU, but the heap is most often used from the little memory inside the CPU, sometimes called the cache, today up to 1MB or 2MB per core which is very fast to access, while the Managed Memory is allocated in the regular RAM. May be cached also, but not with a high likelihood.

Comment: Are you saying that the heap is the same thing as the stack? Are you saying that Memory<T> uses the CPU cache and the standard array uses the "Managed memory"? CPU cache = heap? Managed memory heap? stack? the same? To be honest I didn't understand you comment.

Comment: I talked about likelihood, The stack is an heavily accessed part of memory, therefore the caching algorithm of the CPU, will very like move it to it's cache. It's beyond our control, but it's a possible reason why access to the stack is faster, than to a random unpredictable address in memory.
Actually, you question a lot, but you don't explain or correct anyhting, in case of I have misused a word. That's not very helpful either. 'Unlike Span<T>, Memory<T> can be stored on the managed heap.' from here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/memory-and-spans/memory-t-usage-guidelines